# How to write escape character to string?

Tags: java, escaping

How to write escape character "\" to string?

Comment: i have such code: String newstr = "\";

Comment: java says its ilegal escape character, with "\\" i can't see it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a normal string, you use `\\`

If this is in a regular expression, it needs to be `\\\\`

The reason RegEx needs four is because both the String parser and RegEx engine support escapes.  Therefore, `\\\\` is parsed to `\\` by the String parser then to a literal `\` by the RegEx parser.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the escape character:  `"\\"`

Comment: I've rolled back my original edit to this post because I wasn't sure I knew what you were intending to write :)

Comment: No worries. All fixed now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You escape certain characters by adding "\" in front of the character.

So `\\` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use double \ in string

```
String example = "C:\\Program Files";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\"
```

is the same as

```
 string = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\"
```

in some cases... i'm not 100% sure but i think it might be language dependant... i KNOW "@" works in C#

Comment: Of course it is language dependent :). And it doesn't work in java.

Comment: well since the op didnt mention the language, it was never mentioned until his 2nd comment that it was java... and it's not marked as java, it could have been a valid answer.

Comment: Java appears in the question's tags.  This was tagged as Java by the poster since at most 5 minutes after the question was asked (since it doesn't show as having any edits).

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
String newstr = "\\";
```

`\` is a special character within a string used for escaping.

`"\"` does now work because it is escaping the second `"`.

To get a literal `\` you need to escape it using `\`.